# Error: /bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2.so in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, sdl

I am using Fedora 33 OS, I have G++ compiler.
When I compile my program, it gets this error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2.so
```

I don't know how it can't find this file, because I double checked the library path and I am certain it is located inside there.

The actual file is called libSDL2.so, and I read other post that said to remove lib from the name, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Use `-lSDL2`, without `.so`. *"I read other post that said to remove lib from the name"* Did you rename the file?! They meant that you should use `-lSDL2` instead of `-llibSDL2`, **not** that you should rename the file.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following information: (a) how do you compile the program (command + all options) (b) where is  `libSDL2.so` in your filesystem.